# Vim indentation of a bash script seems broken after a pipe

Tags: bash, indentation

Vim builtin indentation seems to get confused with the following script. I cannot get Vim to indent properly the while-loop after the pipe.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
    # while loop is indented correctly
    while read line
    do
        echo $line
    done < myfile

    # while loop after a pipe is NOT indented correctly despite gg=G
    cat myfile | while read line
do
    echo $line
done
done
```

Running `gg=G` does not fix the indentation.
Any ideas?

Comment: You shouldn't read a file like this in the first place, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: Thanks for pointing the reference.

To me using "cat | while read" more readable that feeding the file at the end of the loop and I am aware of the sub-process restrictions. However the example was just to illustrate the unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Maybe ask on [vi.se]?

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will consider it eventually. In the meantime I chose to feed the input at the end of the while-loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get what you want in this case without writing your own indent script or breaking up the lines like in Nobe4's answer.  Take a look at `GetShIndent()` in `$VIMRUNTIME/indent/sh.vim`

It looks for the **previous** non-blank line that starts with `while` and increases the indent level.  However, it checks if the current line starts with `do` to decrease the indent level.  This is how it sets the correct indent if you use the inline `while ; do` variant.  In your case, it finds the `do` on the current line but not the `while` on the previous line, so it drops the indent level lower than you expected.

Answer (score 3):

I made the indentation works by splitting the `cat`/`while` like so:

```
while true
do
    ...

    cat myfile |
    while read line
    do
        echo $line
    done
done
```

Comment: Ok, that's a start I guess. I was wondering if there was not a vim parameter that I could tweak to get the expected behaviour.